# Matlab: visualizing data with categorical data on the x-axis

Tags: matlab, data-visualization

Okay so I have a dataset with 5 'settings' (let's call them settings for now). Each setting has 3 'games' and each game has 2 'levels'. On the y-axis I have the score on the level of the game in a certain setting. I want to visualize this in Matlab, but I find it hard to know how I should structure this. Is it possible to use different signs (star, circle, etc.) for the games and different colors for each of the two levels in the games? I know you can tweak these parameters in Matlab, but I have no idea of how to do this in this case. I find it hard to solve this problem, because I want to have categorical data on the x-axis and a continuous score-scale on the y-axis. I hope someone understands this, because it's hard to explain and there are many categorical fields to take care of.

Here is an example of my dataset:
http://i63.tinypic.com/302s1h4.png

Comment: There are several possible representations of this dataset. Could you add an example of how the output should look like? You can draw it or explain it precisely...

Comment: I would like to compare the scores on (the levels in) the games in different settings. So it are the settings that have to be compared. I want to see which setting is the best for the games (or the levels in the games).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stem plots:

```
%% create data matrices for each setting (could have been just a single 3-D matrix)
data1 = [3.76 3.89; 4.98 6.78; 72.0 72.8];
data2 = [4.48 5.31; 6.67 6.68; 130.2 136.5];

%% create new figure window, and set hold on to issue multiple plots to the same figure
f= figure;
hold on;

%% plot setting one in (r)ed
stem3(data1, 'r')
%% plot setting two in (b)lue
stem3(data2, 'b')

%% label the axes
xlabel('level');
ylabel('game');
zlabel('score');
%% add a legend to keep track of which color goes with which setting
legend({'setting1', 'setting2'})

%% Adding these last two settings to improve view because they are not default on some matlab versions
grid on;
view(-53, 29);  %% choose an isometric viewpoint

%% update x/y axis tick marks
ax = gca;  %% get handle to current axes
ax.XTick = [1 2];  %% for MATLAB 2014b and above
ax.YTick = [1 2 3];

%% For 2014a and earlier
%%  ax = gca;
%%  set(ax,'XTick', [1 2]);
%%  set(ax,'YTick', [1 2 3]);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to remove the 1.5 and 2.5's, because they are no valid option?